# New Game activity in Android: what UI choices?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

My Android game project needs a "New Game" activity.  The game has a couple of options that should be asked each time a new game is started: the board size and the game seed.  I would like to do this in a form resembling the standard "Settings" activity, but with an added "Start" button at the bottom.  Given that these things will be chosen every new game, they don't want to be hidden away in the app's Settings activity. So what's the best way to go about this?

Things I've investigated:

1. Using a custom PreferenceActivity, since the behaviour is almost the same.  Since the PreferenceActivity doesn't use layout XML files I can't see a way of adding a button to it.
2. A Linear layout that includes a ListView and a Button.  I've started implementing this, but I can't even find a way to add items to the ListView - the ListView guide in the documentation certainly isn't aimed at a beginner like me!  And then the list items need to be interactive to allow options to be selected: this looks like a lot of work to duplicate what PreferenceActivity almost does on its own.

Is there an option that I'm missing?  I've spent a couple of hours trying to find an answer in the documentation and in previous questions, but with no progress.  If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Comment: A PreferenceActivity is not the way to go. You add items to a ListView through the adapter you set on the ListView with the setAdapter() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code for you. Hope it will be useful.
You should go by the second way and use `LinearLayout` (this is `main.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
 android:id="@+id/lvSimple"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

<Button // describe your start button here/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for ListView item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/ivImg"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher">
</ImageView>
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<CheckBox
 android:id="@+id/cbChecked"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="CheckBox">
</CheckBox>
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/tvText"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="right"
 android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
 android:text="TextView">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  // имена атрибутов для Map
  final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT = "text";
  final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_CHECKED = "checked";
  final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE = "image";

  ListView lvSimple;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // data array
    String[] texts = { "sometext 1", "sometext 2", "sometext 3",
        "sometext 4", "sometext 5" };
    boolean[] checked = { true, false, false, true, false };
    int img = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    // our data source
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
        texts.length);
    Map<String, Object> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
      m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, texts[i]);
      m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_CHECKED, checked[i]);
      m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE, img);
      data.add(m);
    }

    String[] from = { ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_CHECKED,
        ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE };
    // array of IDs of Views
    int[] to = { R.id.tvText, R.id.cbChecked, R.id.ivImg };

    // create adapter
    SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item,
        from, to);

    // create ListView and set the adapter
    lvSimple = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSimple);
    lvSimple.setAdapter(sAdapter);
  }
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for this! I've started by integrating it into my project as is, before I play with it. But there's are two unresolved symbols in the Java code: R.id.lvSimple and R.layout.item.  My best guess is that that R.id.lvSimple should be the id for the outer LinearLayout: am I right? As for R.layout.item, I'm at a loss: I don't understand the code well enough yet to make a guess.

Comment: lvSimple is id of ListView in main.xml. probably, you made a mistake when merge my code with your own)